# Has Sun deprecated Java DTD URLs?

Tags: java, ant, dtd, sun, xmltask

We use the [xmltask](http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/) ANT task for conditional logic (ie: if statements) in our ANT scripts.

Currently this task is bombing, apparently because can't reach "http://java.sun.com/dtd/application_1_3.dtd".   We can't access this URL either in our browser.  Has Sun "deprecated" these Java DTD URL's?

---

Update: Appears http://java.sun.com/ is not available either.  Not sure if this is a outage on Sun/Oracle's end or if this site has been decommissioned.

Update 2: Ok, now it is working.  Hasn't been working since yesterday - I swear!  I think @Jeremy is right we need to host this ourselves.

Comment: Sun ? Who is Sun ? anyway opens well in browser here

Comment: I can access this url using browser(FF).

Comment: We all know Sun bought Oracle and is just using them as a facade for all their evil empire ideas. Obviously it's not working.

Comment: Works on my side.... `java.sun.com redirects you to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index.html

Comment: Sun bought Oracle, yeah that was the right thing to do !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you just download it and host it yourself.

http://java.sun.com/dtd/

Comment: Yes, good idea.  But I believe this URL is hard coded somewhere in xmltask.  If I just download the file I would think the xmltask jar would need to be updated - I guess we could do this..

Comment: Ah, that's not good. Has your network changed? Maybe proxy settings?

Answer (score 0):

It's not being deprecated. It's a temporary issue, according to [this thread](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=9148770#9148770).

Anyway, depending on externally hosted DTDs is a bad idea anyway and should be avoided.

Since the URIs are used as identifier, changing them isn't trivial, sometimes. However every XML parser should have an option to customize how DTDs (or Schemas) are loaded and it should be possible to use a local copy instead of the remote one. Additionally this would reduce the need for external connectivity and would speed up loading the XML.

Answer (score 0):

Being able to build stuff without having network access is kind of nice.  Here's an example of self-hosted DTDs and xmltask, for posterity.

Somewhere near the top of the build file (${ext.dir} being a local file path):

```
<xmlcatalog id="commonDTDs">
    <dtd publicId="-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN" location="${ext.dir}/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" />
    <dtd publicId="-//tuckey.org//DTD UrlRewrite 3.2//EN" location="${ext.dir}/dtd/urlrewrite3.2.dtd" />
</xmlcatalog>
```

reference it later using [xmlcatalog](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/xmlcatalog.html) refId:

```
<xmltask source="${war.dir}/WEB-INF/web.xml" dest="${war.dir}/WEB-INF/web.xml">
    <xmlcatalog refId="commonDTDs" />
    <remove path="web-app/servlet[servlet-class/text()='loader.servlet.FileServlet']" />
    <remove path="web-app/servlet-mapping[servlet-name/text()='FileServlet']" />
</xmltask>
```